# Syntax Error, Unexpected (arg, expecting keyword_do error message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I attempt to  load the page I'm getting the following error message:

syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' link_to "UP", link_vote_path (link) )

The line in reference is pointing to is the second and third line here:

```
    <td><%= link.totalcount %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "UP", link_vote_path (link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "DOWN", link_down_vote_path (link) %></td>
```

I believe I have the correct route in place so I'm a bit confused as to the error message.

Basically I'm trying to add in a simple counter in Rails that allows for voting up and down. Using the following routes:

```
           link_vote GET    /links/:link_id/vote(.:format)      links#vote
      link_link_vote GET    /links/:link_id/link_vote(.:format) links#link_vote
      link_down_vote GET    /links/:link_id/down_vote(.:format) links#down_vote
```

And have the following in my controller:

```
  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)
    @link.user = current_user
    @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
      if @link.save
        redirect_to @link
      else
        render :new
      end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
       else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def vote
    if current_user
      @link.vote << Vote.create!(user_id: @link.user_id, link_id: @link.id)
      @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
      @link.save
      redirect_to :root
    else
      redirect_to :login
    end
  end

  def link_vote
    @link.votes << Vote.create!(user_id: @link.user_id, link_id: @link.id)
    @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
    @link.save
    redirect_to :root
  end

  def down_vote
    @link.votes.last.destroy
    @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
    @link.save
    redirect_to :root
  end
```

Am I missing something in my controller that's affecting the counter?

Comment: As a new person to using Rails and not knowing it was a simple typographical error...this is a bit cruel. If I had known it was a simple correction regarding space then I wouldn't have come to StackOverflow for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put a space before opening parenthesis of a method call

```
<%= link_to "UP", link_vote_path(link) %>
```